# Facebook group feed on my website

Tags: feed, facebook-stream-story

I manage a website for a sporting organisation and I want to have a section on the site that streams the organisation's Facebook activity.

The organisation is an "open group".

I've tried using the "Activity Feed" plugin, but all it shows is activity in relation to the organisation's website or domain.   I want the feed to show everything from the group.

Also, in relation to the existing "feed" there is a variable "data-site"... in the instructions, it says this is required and you can use two domains (eg. domain.org.au and www.domain.org.au). How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just try [Wallflux](http://www.wallflux.com), in conjunction with for example [Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/). That does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a privacy thing that you can only show posts from the group owner in an external feed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RebelMouse plugin : http://wordpress.org/plugins/rebelmouse-widget/

"Add your RebelMouse to your blog! RebelMouse is your social front page; connect all of your social networks to create a beautiful, dynamic site in seconds. RebelMouse shows the world what you care about and automatically updates as you share. You'll need to sign up (free) at RebelMouse.com to use the plugin."

or the Custom Facebook Feed Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/

"Display feeds from multiple different Facebook pages/groups and use the shortcode to embed them into a page, post or widget anywhere on your site"